# Using Valgrind with RInside programs

Tags: c++, r, valgrind, rcpp, rinside

Does anyone know how to use Valgrind to memory debug RInside programs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use [RInside](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rinside.html), you create a standalone C++ program---which happens to be linked with [R](http://www.r-project.org) such that [R](http://www.r-project.org) gets embedded.

The use of [valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org) is therefore no different then with another C++ program.  All code that you want valgrind to analyse may have to rebuilt with the proper setup (see [preparing your program](http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html#quick-start.prepare) at the Valgrind site) and that includes [R](http://www.r-project.org) and [RInside](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rinside.html) if you want Valgrind output on these components too.

Comment: Compiling a simple program:
`#include <RInside.h>
int main(){
    RInside R;
}`
with
`g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -I/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include -I/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RInside/include -pipe -O0 -g -Wall    testv.cpp  -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lR  -lblas -llapack -L/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/lib -lRcpp -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/lib -L/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RInside/lib -lRInside -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RInside/lib -o testv`
i got this [link](http://pastebin.com/xVazvqaF)
There were errors!

Comment: Thanks for posting that. I am not a great Valgrind user, but that looks *clean* to me: it reports some issues stemming from libz (which R links to) but nothing in R (or RInside) itself. So no issue.  To **really** prove that point you could actually add an explicit on purpose leak (ie assign ten times 100k of memory in a loop and never free it) and you should see Valgrind putting the finger on that error.

Comment: Is it possible to suppress issues originating from libz and other codes, since an RInside user would probably ignore them?